# web.xml filter won't run on static content

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

Does anyone know why a web.xml filter wouldn't be run when serving a welcome file, or any static content? It seems to only run on URLs that are mapped to a servlet. How can I get the filter functionality on static content?

Here's what I'm using:

```
  <filter>
     <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
     <filter-class>com.domain.project.server.service.MyFilter</filter-class>
  </filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
 </filter-mapping>

<filter>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <filter-class>org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy</filter-class>
</filter>

 <filter-mapping>
    <filter-name>springSecurityFilterChain</filter-name>
    <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>

  <welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>WelcomeFile.html</welcome-file>
  </welcome-file-list>
```

Comment: Change your url pattern to '/' and try.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried it and that makes it not work for anything.  :(

Comment: you have any other filters??

Comment: @SrinivasuTalluri Yes, one more for Spring.  I'll add above.

Comment: Is the filter order is there as specified as above {user your filter before spring}

Comment: @SrinivasuTalluri Yes, that's the order I'm using it in.

Comment: First remove the Spring filter try for  the static content , then add the spring filter try again ....

Comment: I faced similar issue, not exactly same. Check if that helps - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28459947/welcome-file-list-not-working-in-jetty-spring/28471027#28471027

Answer (score 2):

Yay! [This](http://www.coderanch.com/t/526355/Servlets/java/Filter-mapping-static-files) was it. Silly app engine config needs to be told not to circumvent your config in the interest of optimization.  I added the WelcomeFile.html line to appengine-web.xml to get it working:

```
  <!-- Configure serving/caching of GWT files -->
  <static-files>
    <include path="**" />

    <!-- The following line requires App Engine 1.3.2 SDK -->
    <include path="**.nocache.*" expiration="0s" />

    <include path="**.cache.*" expiration="365d" />
    <exclude path="**.gwt.rpc" />
    <exclude path="**WelcomeFile.html" />
  </static-files>
```

Comment: Please note that this is in the docs: https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/webxml#Filters and https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/config/appconfig#Java_appengine_web_xml_Static_files_and_resource_files

Answer (score 0):

You could use a filter mapping ?

```
<filter-mapping>
  <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
  <url-pattern>/index.html</url-pattern>
</filter-mapping>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public void doFilter(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response, FilterChain chain) throws IOException, ServletException {
        String url = ((HttpServletRequest) request).getRequestURI();
        LOGGER.info(url);
        if (url.endsWith(".js") || url.endsWith(".css") || url.endsWith(".html")) {
            chain.doFilter(request, response);
        }
}
```

Comment: My filter is doing basically that (just System.out.println on first line).  I tried taking out the Spring filter, same results.  Runs for servlet content, but not for static content.

Comment: Do you have any load balancer or webservers in front of the servlet engine  like nginx , apache

Comment: It's a GWT + App Engine project.  I'm testing in dev mode, but the same thing happens in production.

Comment: That's actually a great suggestion, since I know that GWT agressively caches static content.  I was hopeful, but clearing the cache (and a SHIFT+Refresh for good measure) didn't do it.